# How can I get one match with RegEx from start of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have two strings, program_CRID: "3333313231323132" and series_CRID: "31323132".

The program_CRID is built up with three segments as follows "random_numbers"+"series_CRID"+"episode". For the example for program_CRID above it is:

- random_numbers = 3333
- series_CRID = 31323132
- episode = 3132

So, I want to subtract the random_numbers and series_CRID from the program_CRID and only keep the episode. Note that the length of the 3 segments vary.

```
// this snippet is working
var program_CRID = "3333373638353131";
var series_CRID = "3337363835";
var regex = new RegExp("\\d*" + series_CRID, "g");
var episode = program_CRID.replace(regex, "");
// result is 3131

// this one is not working
var program_CRID = "3333313231323132";
var series_CRID = "31323132";
var regex = new RegExp("\\d*" + series_CRID, "g");
var episode = program_CRID.replace(regex, "");
// result is null but should be 3132 (last four numbers of program_CRID)
```

I have tried adding a ^ to the start and a $ at the end of the regex but with no luck. I have tried removing the "g" and well, a whole lot of other but all in vain. I guess the second part is not working due to that the episode is 3132 the same as the end of the series_CRID. Please help.

Also, this is my first post so please be gentle.

Bonus question: Why do I have to add an extra \ in front of the \d* in order to make it work? According to the documentaiton I have read \d* should be enough. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the length of all three can vary, and they are all the same numbers, and there's nothing separating them, what would be your logic to somehow tell them apart? It seems rather impossible to do.

Comment: the series_CRID will always be a part of the program_CRID and seperate the random_numbers and the episode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
program_CRID = "3333313231323132"; var series_CRID = "31323132"; 
var regex = new RegExp("\\d*" + series_CRID + "(?!$)");
var episode = program_CRID.replace(regex, "");
```

The extra (?!$) will ensure that the matching pattern won't be at the end of the string so repeating string that  follows the series_crid won't be matched.

Also you put the extra forward slash to escape the forward slash part of the digit selector \d.

Comment: Thanks @nanestev, that worked as a charm. I am quite new at this and I learn something new everyday. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
var program_CRID = "3333313231323132";
var series_CRID = "31323132";
var regex = new RegExp("(?!\d*" + series_CRID + ")");
var episode = program_CRID.replace(regex, "");
```

or

```
var program_CRID = "3333313231323132";
var series_CRID = "31323132";
var regex = new RegExp("\\d{4}" + series_CRID, "g");

var episode = program_CRID.replace(regex, "");
```

if the numbers of the first digits is defined.

Comment: Thanks, it worked but the random_numbers is not always 4 digits so it will unfortunately not work for all cases.